# jQuery Drag & Drop Upload with normal upload

Tags: jquery, ajax, image, forms, upload

I'm currently on a project that requires me to create a image upload form using *jQuery Drag & Drop files to the box* feature. I found multiple tutorials around the web and they were good, however, none of them explained how to include an alternative method of clicking the box and opening up the usual *File select* window.

**The box looks like this:**
[image: The box]

The point of me posting this question here is to help me figure out how to make a Drag & Drop upload feature with AJAX that also has the alternative of clicking the box and selecting the files normally (sending occurs through AJAX again)

I'm not very flexible when it comes to jQuery/Javascript/AJAX, hence I asked here.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you add a standard file select after the box?

Comment: I thought of that, but it wouldn't fit the design. The box would have to include both jobs.

Comment: [old question but nevertheless:] Standard-Upload fields are required if javascript is just not available in the client-device.
I'd add a common upload-field and when javascript is available you can hide it in favor of the shown drop-area by javascript.